# search words in ipython-notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Literally , `IPython-Notebook` is notebook. I try to work with it as notebook.

So is there way I can search keywords or more complex search in a collection of ipynb I had written ? Just like Evernote allow you do more complex search for your notes.

Comment: How would you like to search those files? Note that notebooks are stored as json - a simple text-based storage format. So if you want to find keywords you can use system tools like `grep`.

Comment: I met this problem too. The problem with `grep` is that the notebooks contain too much binary data. Slows things down and often you see large blobs of binary and you can't find what you really want. You can't jump to the results quickly neither. Ideally the ipython notebook server should design a search function!

Answer (score 1):

on OS UBUNTU 18.04
I am positioned in my directory called work, and in my dir work there is an directory named
IPYNB where there are all my ipynb files  somes into sub-folders

I m searching for the string “trigFromTanEqL” in one of my ipynb file, so:
I enter the command :**grep  -rnw './' -e "trigFromTanEqL"**

```
SageMath/work$ grep  -rnw './' -e "trigFromTanEqL"
./IPYNB/LinearAlgebraMIT/.ipynb_checkpoints/exoTrigo-checkpoint.ipynb:496:    "trigFromTanEqL=[sin(t_1)==tan(t_1)/(sqrt(1+tan(t_1)^2)), cos(t_1)==1/(sqrt(1+tan(t_1)^2)) , \\\n",
./IPYNB/LinearAlgebraMIT/.ipynb_checkpoints/exoTrigo-checkpoint.ipynb:501:    "ftan(t_1,t_2)=f.subs(trigFromTanEqL)\n",
./IPYNB/LinearAlgebraMIT/exoTrigo.ipynb:496:    "trigFromTanEqL=[sin(t_1)==tan(t_1)/(sqrt(1+tan(t_1)^2)), cos(t_1)==1/(sqrt(1+tan(t_1)^2)) , \\\n",
./IPYNB/LinearAlgebraMIT/exoTrigo.ipynb:501:    "ftan(t_1,t_2)=f.subs(trigFromTanEqL)\n",
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `-rnw`, `./`, and `-e` mean in your grep? It might be helpful to the asker to understand why you've used those particular flags.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google's Toolbar to search for keywords in IPython-Notebook / Jupyter Notebook. Pretty handy

[image]